# updating liquibase changelog files to latest version

Tags: liquibase

I have changelog files specific to liquibase 2

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"                  
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd">
```

These changelog files are processed successfully by latest liquibase (3.2), but it throws and Warning complaining about old schema definition.

I wonder what is better approach to update these changelogs easily except search and replace `dbchangelog-2.0.xsd` with `dbchangelog-3.2.xsd` or an approach to switch to latest version easily in future, or even should we stick to old version of schema definition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning is there simply to remind you that unless you update the schema version, you cannot use new change tags if you add to the changelog file.

If you are not going to modify the file in the future, there is no reason to update the XSD reference besides to remove the warning from the logs. If you do want to update them, a simple search and replace should work just fine.